# How to Write If condition in Angular Expression

Tags: angularjs

I need to place some `if` condition in Angular expression.I want execution of my angular `expression{{}}` based on some condition .

Comment: Why don't you cover the condition in controller? seems that's responsible for data on view.

Comment: I need to show expression evaluation based on some condition ,option chosen by user

Comment: Things like `{{goodToGo && startRace()}}` comes in handy. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

To add an express use

```
{{ 4 > 5 ? 'Four': 'Five'}}
```

Preferred way

```
{{verifyCondition(4, 5)}}

// In your controller

$scope.verifyCondition = function(a, b){
    return a > b ? "True condition": "False condition";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. But Angular 1.1.5 supports ternary operators in expressions:

```
{{"The fee is " + (isMember ? "$2.00" : "$10.00")}}
```

Also I used to do the following a lot to conditionally execute functions in expressions

```
{{goodToGo && startRace()}}
```

`goodToGo` is a simple scope variable.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my expression which I was trying to write :

```
{{ ((entry.default == 'BLANK' || entry.default=='custom' ) ? " " : entry.default || getDefaultValuePlaceholder())}}
```